# Exception thrown: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in System.Data.dll Additional information: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Table'

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

My code generates the following error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>   Additional information:
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'.

My code is:

```
conn.Open();

SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Update [Table] Set [Name]='" + textBox2.Text + "',[Course]='" + comboBox1.Text + "',[YearSection]='" + textBox3.Text + "' Where [Id]='"+textBox1.Text+"')", conn);

sda.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
MessageBox.Show("Updated Successfully !!!");
```

Can someone help me understand why this doesn't work.

Comment: Never use string concatenation to form query, because it leads to sql injection. Use sql parameters instead.

Comment: I recommend using SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) which comes with SQL Server.  I usually verify my queries in SSMS before putting the queries into c# code.  The error message in SSMS are much better than c#.  I also recommend using the string,Format rather then '+' : string.Format("Update [Table] Set [Name]='{1}',[Course]='{0}',[YearSection]='{2}' Where [Id]='{0}'",textBox1.Text, comboBox2.Text,comboBox3.Text);

Answer (score 1):

Remove the ) at the end of your query